# 3 Percent Data needed from every Request

Tags: vba

Here is my code : I have 3 percent data pick up code where in multiple duplicate request on which i have to pick 3 percent data for every Request, Anybody can help me this.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub CopyRows()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NbRows As Long
Dim RowList() 
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long 
Dim RowNb As Long 
'Sheets("Sheet1").Activate 
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
NbRows = IIf(LastRow <> 200, LastRow * 0.03, 20) 
ReDim RowList(1 To NbRows) 
k = 1 
For i = 1 To NbRows RowNb = Rnd() * LastRow 
For j = 1 To k 
If (RowList(j) = RowNb) Then GoTo NextStep 
Next j RowList(k) = RowNb Rows(RowNb).Copy 
Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, "A") 
k = k + 1 
NextStep: Next i End Sub`
```

Here is the sample data:

```
Request Processor Name  Status  Process
131 Ibrar   Completed   CRU
131 Ibrar   Completed   CRU
131 Ibrar   Completed   CRU
131 Ibrar   Completed   CRU
131 Ibrar   Completed   CRU
131 Ibrar   Completed   CRU
131 Ibrar   Completed   CRU
131 Amrita  Completed   CRU
131 Amrita  Completed   CRU
97  Amrita  Completed   CRU
97  Amrita  Completed   CRU
97  Amrita  Completed   CRU
97  Amrita  Completed   CRU
97  Amrita  Completed   CRU
97  Amrita  Completed   CRU
97  Amrita  Completed   CRU
97  Amrita  Completed   CRU
97  Amrita  Completed   CRU
```

I need to extract 3 percent of 131 and 3 percent of 97.

Comment: Do the rows have to be randomly chosen from within a request? You are essentially sampling at the 3% level by the sounds of it.

Comment: When i ran this code its gives me only 3 % data from the whole data but i need 3 percent from every request ID, whether it is duplicate or not. I have data of around 5 thousand and need to pick 3 % of every request ID. Suppose 3 % of 100 is 3 but in this i have 10 different ID which are ten times duplicates so every should have 1   task each from every 10 request ID's. some ids are 5 times duplicates, some 15 some 17 etc.

Comment: You are ignoring my question... does the 3% have to be randomly sampled from a given request or can it be the first 3 percent of rows for a given request? Essentially,  I am asking about sampling distribution and potential bias though I don't know what has already happened to the data.

Comment: Yes, 3% have o be randomly sampled from a given request.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following. Note, if 3% is less than 1 row I select 1 row otherwise I round down to the nearest whole number with Floor function. You could change this.

Function modified from Ozgrid. Link included.

---

Test case:

With sample data of:

[image: Sample data]

Note: I have added a unique row `Id` in column E so can examine results of row selection.

In my sample there are 9 rows with `Request 97` and 87 with `Request 131`. The expected results in terms of selected row counts are shown in the table below:

**Result row counts:**

[image: Data]

---

**Test run with data:**

[image: Test run]

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PasteSampleRows()
    Dim lastRow As Long, dict As Object, arr(),  i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Range("A2:E" & lastRow).Value
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) '<= Get distinct Request and count of associated rows
            If Not dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                dict.Add (arr(i, 1)), 1
            Else
                dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + 1
            End If
        Next i

        Dim key As Variant

        For Each key In dict.keys
            With .Range("A1:E" & lastRow)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=key
                Dim targetNumberRows As Long
                targetNumberRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(0.03 * dict(key), 1)
                If targetNumberRows < 1 Then targetNumberRows = 1
                Dim tempString As String, selectedRows As Range
                tempString = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
                Set selectedRows = RandRows(ws, Replace(Split(tempString, "$")(2), ":", vbNullString), Split(tempString, "$")(4), targetNumberRows)
            End With
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                If Not selectedRows Is Nothing Then
                    selectedRows.Copy .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                End If
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        Next key
    End With
End Sub

Private Function RandRows(ByRef currSheet As Worksheet, ByVal firstRow As Long, ByVal lastRow As Long, ByVal numRows As Long) As Range
    'http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/RandomNumbers.htm
    Dim iArr As Variant, selectedRows As Range, i As Long, r As Long, temp As Long

    Application.Volatile

    ReDim iArr(firstRow To lastRow)

    For i = firstRow To lastRow
        iArr(i) = i
    Next i

    For i = lastRow To firstRow + 1 Step -1
        r = Int(Rnd() * (i - firstRow + 1)) + firstRow
        temp = iArr(r)
        iArr(r) = iArr(i)
        iArr(i) = temp
    Next i

    Dim currRow As Range

    For i = firstRow To firstRow + numRows - 1
        Set currRow = currSheet.Cells.Rows(iArr(i))
        If Not selectedRows Is Nothing Then
            Set selectedRows = Application.Union(selectedRows, currRow)
        Else
            Set selectedRows = currRow
        End If
    Next i

    If Not selectedRows Is Nothing Then
        Set RandRows = selectedRows
    Else
        MsgBox "No rows were selected for copying"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: On which line? Have you got a sheet 1 and sheet 2 - I guess yes because you said it was working.

Comment: sorry i was change the name of  sheet. Thank you again for your help!